# Nav action not executing on Jetpack Navigation

Tags: java, android, navigation, android-jetpack

Facing a weird issue with Jetpack Navigation,any help would be much appreciated. I've a navigation graph as below:

I would like to navigate from one fragment to other two fragments, using jetpack navigation.
So far I've been able to navigate only to the **second_fragment** from **entry_fragment** as shown in the picture below.
[image: Navigation Graph]

My EntryFragment.class :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_entry,container,false);
    v.findViewById(R.id.fragmentOneButton).setOnClickListener(ls);
    v.findViewById(R.id.fragmentTwoButton).setOnClickListener(ls);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}

private final View.OnClickListener ls = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.fragmentOneButton:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "First Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.action_entry_fragment_to_first_fragment).onClick(view);
                break;
            case R.id.fragmentTwoButton:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Second Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.action_entry_fragment_to_second_fragment).onClick(view);
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

On First Button Click I'm only getting the toast and on clicking the second button I can actually navigate to **SecondFragment**. What I'm i doing wrong here? and what is the best practice to navigate using Navigation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try using `NavHostFragment.findNavController(fragment).navigate(R.id.action_created_from_graph)`
instead of Navigation.createNavigateOnCLickListener

I'm going off my memory, so the syntax might be a little off, but that's the jist of it.

Comment: This was my first approach, didn't work out. It still redirects to only the second fragment.

Comment: I would double check your nav graph, and also, it might be worth trying to separate your onClick listeners for each view instead of using a switch case - simplifying the logic as much as possible helps when debugging and you can always refactor later.